# Error with pyrDown

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am new to working with OpenCV, I am implementing a hierarchical search for template matching, and in a step, I need to downsample an image. However, I get the noted error.

Another point is when I comment out the first `pyrDown`, it works for the second one, the first `pyrDown` is generating the error, but I don't know why. Someone, please help me understand why this happens.

```
        Mat sampled_image,sampled_reference;

        GaussianBlur( prev_image , filtered_image , Size( 5, 5 ), 0 ,0 );
        GaussianBlur(prev_reference, filtered_reference, Size(5,5), 0, 0);


         pyrDown( filtered_image, sampled_image, Size(filtered_image.rows/2 , filtered_image.cols/2));

         pyrDown( filtered_reference, sampled_reference, Size(filtered_reference.rows/2 , filtered_reference.cols/2));


        image_array.push(sampled_image); // level 1 image   LEVEL 1 IMAGE
        reference_array.push(sampled_reference); // level 1 reference

        prev_image = sampled_image;
        prev_reference= sampled_reference;
```

Error thrown:

```
Width = 480 Height= 300 (of the filtered_image )
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 && std::abs(dsize.width*2 - ssize.width) <= 2 && std::abs(dsize.height*2 - ssize.height) <= 2) in pyrDown_, file C:\opencv-3.2.0\source\modules\imgproc\src\pyramids.cpp, line 873
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  C:\opencv-3.2.0\source\modules\imgproc\src\pyramids.cpp:873: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 && std::abs(dsize.width*2 - ssize.width) <= 2 && std::abs(dsize.height*2 - ssize.height) <= 2 in function pyrDown_
```

Comment: Try passing `Size((filtered_image.rows+1)/2,(filtered_image.cols+1)/2)`.

Comment: I have tried that, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the dimensions of both images I can't be sure, but I have a feeling your reference image is square.

OpenCV [pyrdown](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrdown#pyrdown) documentation (it's for opencv 2.4, but you get redirected there from 3.0 so it should stand. Here's the important part:

```
|dstsize.width  * 2 - src.cols| <= 2
|dstsize.height * 2 - src.rows| <= 2
```

This is the assertion that fails. I think you have swapped the coordinates, which can get unnoticed with square image (rows==cols) but fails otherwise.

The size should be (width, height) form. Width is the number of columns, height is the number of rows. Try doing:

```
cv::pyrDown( input, output, Size( input.cols/2, input.rows/2 );
```